# Sprockets::FileNotFound...could not find css file

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have code that has worked for a similar iteration of this site previously, but am now running up against this error...

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Quarterback#index
```

with the detail of...

```
couldn't find file '../../../../xoi_f/app/assets/stylesheets/public.css' under '/Users/Charlie/Sites/xoi_g/app/assets/stylesheets' with type 'text/css'
```

The file `public.css` does in fact exist, and in the `application.css` file, I have he requirements...

```
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require ../../../../xoi_f/app/assets/stylesheets/public.css
 *= require ../../../../xoi_f/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

And in the `admin.html.erb` file, I have the link tag

```
<head>
    <title>XOI Admin | <%= @page_title || "Admin" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag('application', :media => 'all') %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
```

But it doesn't seem to be finding the .css file.

Very much appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Uh, why are you requiring a file from a different rails app?

Comment: Sorry...I'm very new. I've never coded before and have learned as much as I can in a month. Where are you seeing that I'm requiring a file from a different app? I'm sure it's obvious, but I'm new to this.

Comment: The really long relative paths in your `application.css`  (`../../../../xoi_f/app/assets/stylesheets/public.css`) tells me that the files are most likely in another rails app. This is bound to cause all kinds of headaches. If you want to share assets between rails projects then the answer is using [rails engines](http://blog.socialcast.com/organzie-your-assets-with-rails-engines/)

Comment: That was it. Now I get it. I just learned how to use version control, but before I did, had copied the file a few times to not save over changes. I think in that process it began to add this directory info. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@papirtiger, you were correct. I'm new to this, and just learned how to use version control. Prior to using version control, I made copies of the entire project as I was learning. That's when the additional directory info must have been added.

So just simplifying the info to this worked:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require public
 *= require admin
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

So much to learn! I really appreciate the patience with my rookie moves!